# How to compare MySQL timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I am pulling a row from a mysql database which has a time stamp, like this: 2010-10-10 16:56:23

I need to compare this time stamp to the current time from the date object, and see if 30 minutes has passed.

thanks!

Comment: What are you using to pull the row from the database?

Comment: you may consider converting both to UNIX Epoch time and do a simple calculation then. I am just not able to give you the solution since now it is working time :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(new Date() - Date.parse('2010-10-10 16:56:23')) >= 1000 * 60 * 30 // (current date - date) >= 30 minutes
```

I'm not sure about the whole time zone thing though.. if the timezones between the server and user are different you may need to mess around with that.

Answer (score 0):

2010-10-10 16:56:23

make it  20101010165623

get current time also in this format

Just compare bot as integer itself.

You got it!.

Or

mysql have datediff() function which will help you.

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp

in the example , your case second paramtere will be now()

Comment: Wrong.  This cannot be used to check whether 30 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_ADD function and cast date type to your string

```
NOW() > DATE_ADD(CAST('2010-10-10 16:56:23' AS date), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast